# Asymptotic of highly oscillatory summand $\sin^2\left(\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n}\right)$

Tags: analysis, summation-method

How to get an asymptotic of following sum :

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x \sin^2\left(\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n}\right).$$

Note: Quick investigation tells Classical Euler summation fails.

Comment: I'll guess that the leading term is $\frac x2$.

Comment: Why don't you just write $(n-1)!$ instead of $\Gamma(n)$?

Comment: @amsmath to make the factorial continuous as of possibility of differentiation treatment .

Comment: I hope that $x\in\mathbb N$. Otherwise I don't understand the term $\sum_{n=1}^x$.

Comment: @asamath Yeah x belongs to positive integer

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = \Gamma(n)/n$.  Of course $\sin^2(a_n) = 1/2 -\cos(2 a_n)/2$.  I would expect that for all positive integers $\ell$, 
$$\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=1}^x \exp(i \ell a_n) \to 0 \ \text{as}\ x \to \infty$$
which by Weyl's criterion is equivalent to the sequence $a_n$ being equidistributed mod $2\pi$.  But I doubt that this is easy to prove.

Comment: Also can someone comment on asymptotics of$\int_1^x sin^2(\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n})dn $ as $x \rightarrow \infty $